# Django: Model parameter in the URL template tag

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls, django-templates

I want to use the url template tag for my generic view.

I have been searching a lot about this and I didn't find what I want, but it seems a simple issue.

I will use the example that the [Django book, Making a View Generic](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter08.html), has used:

```
# urls.py

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite import models, views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^events/$', views.object_list, {'model': models.Event}),
    (r'^blog/entries/$', views.object_list, {'model': models.BlogEntry}),
)

# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

def object_list(request, model):
    obj_list = model.objects.all()
    template_name = 'mysite/%s_list.html' % model.__name__.lower()
    return render(request, template_name, {'object_list': obj_list})
```

So, I have one view for two URLs, my question is: How can I use the django URL template tag for this two URLs?

I want to do something like this in the html template:

```
href={% url "mysite.views.object_list" model="Event" %}
href={% url "mysite.views.object_list" model="BlogEntry" %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define name for the url:

```
(r'^events/$', views.object_list, {'model': models.Event}, name='my_name'),
```

and use it instead of the view path:

```
href={% url "my_name" model="Event" %}
```

Comment: Yes, it was that, the only two things: It's enough with the name, now it is not necessary the parameter. href={% url "my_name" %} and my big mistake and why it did not work for me, the name for the url , it is necessary to use url function: url(r'^events/$', views.object_list, {'model': models.Event}, name='my_name'),